# TypeError: PgMock2 is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am working on mocking `pg` query, I found a npm package  [PGMock2](https://jfavrod.github.io/pgmock2/) and that suggested importing like

```
import PgMock2 from 'pgmock2';
const pg = new PgMock2();
```

By using above, I am getting error `TypeError: PgMock2 is not a constructor`. Any idea ?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript or JavaScript? In the docs you have linked, the usage for JavaScript shows importing the default from the module.

Comment: I am using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to console `PgMock2` and found `PgMock2` that I need to do `PgMock2.default()` and then it worked. Documentation was missing it.